# Access is denied. Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

Having this  error-
Arduino: 1.8.8 Hourly Build 2018/11/30 12:33 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

open sketch\LCD.ino.cpp: Access is denied.
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High likely one of the intermediate/binary files is in use. For example:

- When you have it already opened in a debug session
- Having it opened in multiple instances of your IDE
- Having it opened in another application
- Having closed an application that locked the intermediate/binary file(s).

What you can do:

- Close the debug session
- Close all applications related to the project
- Restart your computer